# Return value between two characters in a string

Tags: r, regex, substring

I'm trying to extract values in a form from a word document so that I can tabulate them. I used the antiword package to convert the .doc into a character string, now I'd like to pull out values based on markers within the document.

For example

```
example<- 'CONTACT INFORMATION\r\n\r\nName:  John Smith\r\n\r\nphone:  XXX-XXX-XXXX\r\n\r\n' 
Name<- grep('\nName:', example, value = TRUE)
Name
```

> This code returns the whole string when I'd like it to just return 'John Smith'.

Is there a way to add an end marker to the `grep()`? I've also tried `str_extract()` but I'm having trouble formatting my pattern to regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to remove the substring that include `Name:` and after those characters that start after the `\r` by matching the pattern and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub(".*Name:\\s+|\r.*", "", example)
#[1] "John Smith"
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my example code, but not when I try to implement it to the actual word .doc I have. My understanding of regex is very low, but I found that when I modified the code to  gsub(".*\\sName:\\s+|\r.*", "", example), it worked again

Answer (score 1):

We can also use:

```
strsplit(stringr::str_extract_all(example,"\\\nName:.*",simplify = T),":  ")[[1]][2]
#[1] "John Smith"
```